# How to print and print preview my table only with a selected row and value instead of all the row and values?

Tags: c#, forms, printing, preview

When print preview button is clicked, it displays all the data that is going to be print. I only want to select the row that I want, and let it print. And I want each field to have each own line, because also since I have too many fields, my mcCentre and nFirstName cannot display on the print preview.

(etc on the print preview)

appointmentID : 2

pDate : 5/3/2014

aTime : 11.30am

aStatus : waiting

...(continue until the last field)

My AppointmentForm
[image: appointmentform]

AppointmentPrintPreview once print preview button is clicked
[image: printpreview]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace GRP_02_03_SACP
{
    public partial class appointment : Form
    {

        // Data Table to store employee data
        DataTable Appointment = new DataTable();

        // Keeps track of which row in Gridview
        // is selected
        DataGridViewRow currentRow = null;

        SqlDataAdapter AppointmentAdapter;

        public appointment()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void appointment_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadMedicalCentreRecords();
        }



        private void LoadMedicalCentreRecords()
        {

            //retrieve connection information info from App.config
            string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sacpConnection"].ConnectionString;
            //STEP 1: Create connection
            SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
            //STEP 2: Create command
            string strCommandText = "SELECT appointmentID, aDate, aTime, aStatus, aContact, aHeight, aWeight, p.pFirstName , m.mcCentre , n.nFirstName FROM APPOINTMENT AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN Nurse AS n ON a.nurseID = n.NurseID Left outer join Patient as p on a.patientid = p.patientId left outer join medicalcentre as m on a.mcID = m.mcid";

            AppointmentAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strCommandText, myConnect);

            //command builder generates Select, update, delete and insert SQL
            // statements for MedicalCentreAdapter
            SqlCommandBuilder cmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(AppointmentAdapter);
            // Empty Employee Table first
            Appointment.Clear();
            // Fill Employee Table with data retrieved by data adapter
            // using SELECT statement
            AppointmentAdapter.Fill(Appointment);

            // if there are records, bind to Grid view & display
            if (Appointment.Rows.Count > 0)
                grdApp.DataSource = Appointment;
        }

        private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int modifiedRows = 0;
            // Get changes
            DataTable UpdatedTable = Appointment.GetChanges();
            if (UpdatedTable != null)
            {
                // there are changes
                // Write modified data to database 
                modifiedRows = AppointmentAdapter.Update(UpdatedTable);
                // accept changes
                Appointment.AcceptChanges();
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("there are no changes to update");

            if (modifiedRows > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There are " + modifiedRows + " records updated");
                LoadMedicalCentreRecords();
            }
        }

        private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (printDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) // this displays the dialog box and performs actions dependant on which option chosen.
            {
                printDocument1.Print();
            }
        }

        private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            int columnPosition = 0;
            int rowPosition = 25;

            // run function to draw headers
            DrawHeader(new Font(this.Font, FontStyle.Bold), e.Graphics, ref columnPosition, ref rowPosition); // runs the DrawHeader function

            rowPosition += 35; // sets the distance below the header text and the next black line (ruler)

            // run function to draw each row
            DrawGridBody(e.Graphics, ref columnPosition, ref rowPosition);
        }

        // DrawHeader will draw the column title, move over, draw the next column title, move over, and continue.
        private int DrawHeader(Font boldFont, Graphics g, ref int columnPosition, ref int rowPosition)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn dc in grdApp.Columns)
            {

                //MessageBox.Show("dc = " + dc);

                g.DrawString(dc.HeaderText, boldFont, Brushes.Black, (float)columnPosition, (float)rowPosition);
                columnPosition += dc.Width + 5; // adds to colPos. value the width value of the column + 5. 
            }

            return columnPosition;
        }

        /* DrawGridBody will loop though each row and draw it on the screen. It starts by drawing a solid line on the screen, 
         * then it moves down a row and draws the data from the first grid column, then it moves over, then draws the data from the next column,
         * moves over, draws the data from the next column, and continus this pattern. When the entire row is drawn it starts over and draws
         * a solid line then the row data, then the next solid line and then row data, etc.
        */
        private void DrawGridBody(Graphics g, ref int columnPosition, ref int rowPosition)
        {
            // loop through each row and draw the data to the graphics surface.
            foreach (DataRow dr in ((DataTable)grdApp.DataSource).Rows)
            {
                columnPosition = 0;

                // draw a line to separate the rows 
                g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, new Point(0, rowPosition), new Point(this.Width, rowPosition));

                // loop through each column in the row, and draw the individual data item
                foreach (DataGridViewColumn dc in grdApp.Columns)
                {
                    // draw string in the column
                    string text = dr[dc.DataPropertyName].ToString();
                    g.DrawString(text, this.Font, Brushes.Black, (float)columnPosition, (float)rowPosition + 10f); // the last number (10f) sets the space between the black line (ruler) and the text below it.

                    // go to the next column position
                    columnPosition += dc.Width + 5;
                }

                // go to the next row position
                rowPosition = rowPosition + 60; // this sets the space between the row text and the black line below it (ruler).
            }
        }

        private void btnPrintPreview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // PrintPreviewDialog printPreviewDialog1 = new PrintPreviewDialog(); // instantiate new print preview dialog
                printPreviewDialog1.Document = this.printDocument1;
                if (printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) // Show the print preview dialog, uses printPage event to draw preview screen
                {
                    printDocument1.Print();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(exp.Message.ToString());
            }
        }




    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Print Grid view all Data Show with paging in PrintPrivew 
Try This Perfect Working..

```
private void printDocumentRpt_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            int iLeftMargin = e.MarginBounds.Left;
            int iTopMargin = e.MarginBounds.Top;
            bool bMorePagesToPrint = false;
            int iTmpWidth = 0;
            if (bFirstPage)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewColumn GridCol in GvShowData.Columns)
                {
                    iTmpWidth = (int)(Math.Floor((double)((double)GridCol.Width /
                                    (double)iTotalWidth * (double)iTotalWidth *
                                    ((double)e.MarginBounds.Width / (double)iTotalWidth))));
                    iHeaderHeight = (int)(e.Graphics.MeasureString(GridCol.HeaderText,
                                    GridCol.InheritedStyle.Font, iTmpWidth).Height) + 22;

                    arrColumnLefts.Add(iLeftMargin);
                    arrColumnWidths.Add(iTmpWidth);
                    iLeftMargin += iTmpWidth;
                }
            }

            while (iRow <= GvShowData.Rows.Count - 1)
            {
                DataGridViewRow GridRow = GvShowData.Rows[iRow];

                iCellHeight = GridRow.Height + 15;
                int iCount = 0;
                double totalcount = Convert.ToDouble(iRow) % Convert.ToDouble(10);
                if (totalcount == 0 && iRow != 0 && totalrecord == 0)
                {
                    bNewPage = true;
                    bFirstPage = false;
                    bMorePagesToPrint = true;
                    totalrecord = 1;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (bNewPage)
                    {
                        e.Graphics.DrawString("Gridview Header", new System.Drawing.Font(GvShowData.Font, FontStyle.Bold),
                                                            Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left, e.MarginBounds.Top -
                                                            e.Graphics.MeasureString("Gridview Header", new System.Drawing.Font(GvShowData.Font,
                                                            FontStyle.Bold), e.MarginBounds.Width).Height - 13);

                        String strDate = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(strDate, new System.Drawing.Font(GvShowData.Font, FontStyle.Bold),
                                Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left + (e.MarginBounds.Width -
                                e.Graphics.MeasureString(strDate, new System.Drawing.Font(GvShowData.Font,
                                FontStyle.Bold), e.MarginBounds.Width).Width), e.MarginBounds.Top -
                                e.Graphics.MeasureString("Gridview Header", new System.Drawing.Font(new System.Drawing.Font(GvShowData.Font,
                                FontStyle.Bold), FontStyle.Bold), e.MarginBounds.Width).Height - 13);
                        iTopMargin = e.MarginBounds.Top;
                        foreach (DataGridViewColumn GridCol in GvShowData.Columns)
                        {
                            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.LightGray),
                                new System.Drawing.Rectangle((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], iTopMargin,
                                (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], iHeaderHeight));

                            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black,
                                new System.Drawing.Rectangle((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], iTopMargin,
                                (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], iHeaderHeight));

                            e.Graphics.DrawString(GridCol.HeaderText, GridCol.InheritedStyle.Font,
                                new SolidBrush(GridCol.InheritedStyle.ForeColor),
                                new RectangleF((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], iTopMargin,
                                (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], iHeaderHeight), strFormat);
                            iCount++;
                        }
                        bNewPage = false;
                        iTopMargin += iHeaderHeight;
                    }
                    iCount = 0;

                    foreach (DataGridViewCell Cel in GridRow.Cells)
                    {
                        if (Cel.Value != null)
                        {
                            e.Graphics.DrawString(Cel.Value.ToString(), Cel.InheritedStyle.Font,
                                        new SolidBrush(Cel.InheritedStyle.ForeColor),
                                        new RectangleF((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], (float)iTopMargin,
                                        (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], (float)iCellHeight), strFormat);
                        }
                        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, new Rectangle((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount],
                                iTopMargin, (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], iCellHeight));

                        iCount++;
                    }
                }

                iRow++;
                iTopMargin += iCellHeight;
                totalrecord = 0;
            }
            if (bMorePagesToPrint)
                e.HasMorePages = true;
            else
                e.HasMorePages = false;
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

private void printDocumentRpt_BeginPrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            strFormat = new StringFormat();
            strFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
            strFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            strFormat.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter;
            arrColumnLefts.Clear();
            arrColumnWidths.Clear();
            iCellHeight = 0;
            iRow = 0;
            bFirstPage = true;
            bNewPage = true;
            iTotalWidth = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn dgvGridCol in GvShowData.Columns)
            {
                iTotalWidth += dgvGridCol.Width;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        printDocumentRpt.DocumentName = "Test Page Print";
        printPreviewDialogRpt.Document = printDocumentRpt;
        printPreviewDialogRpt.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.